# Handler class for converting opportunity products to assets when the opportunity is closed/won

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to develop a "Handler class" for converting opportunity products to assets when the opportunity is closed/won
Any code would be very much appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: We can just suggest you that how to do this, you have to code that yourself. Write a trigger on `Opportunity` object, Events: after insert, after the update and here write the code to convert `Product` to `Asset`.

Comment: Ok no problem....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should try this this code,and also update your trigger class .

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert,after update)
{
 OpportunityTriggerHandler.testhandler(trigger.new);
}
```

**Handler Class**

```
        public Class OpportunityTriggerHandler
{
    public static void testhandler(List <Opportunity> oplist)
    {
      list <OpportunityLineItem> OLI=new list<OpportunityLineItem>();
       list<Asset> ast = new list<Asset>();
   for(Opportunity o: oplist)
   {
    if(o.isWon == true && o.HasOpportunityLineItem == true && o.AccountId !=null)
    {
     String opptyId = o.Id;
     OLI = [Select UnitPrice, Quantity , PricebookEntry.Product2Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Description
                                  From OpportunityLineItem
                                  where OpportunityId = :opptyId ];

     Asset a = new Asset();
    for(OpportunityLineItem ol: OLI{
      a = new Asset();
      a.AccountId = o.AccountId;
      a.Product2Id = ol.PricebookEntry.Product2Id;
      a.Quantity = ol.Quantity;
      a.Price =  ol.UnitPrice;
      a.PurchaseDate = o.CloseDate;
      a.Status = 'Purchased';
      a.Description = ol.Description;
      a.Name = ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
      ast.add(a);

     }

   }
   }
         update OLI;
    insert ast;
}
}
```

I hope it will help you.
Regards,
Ajay

Please mark my answer as a solution if it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks user351004 for selecting my answer as a best answer .It's my pleasure to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Trigger

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {
   if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isAfter){
      OpportunityTriggerHandler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new);
   }
   if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
      OpportunityTriggerHandler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new,trigger.old);
   }
}
```

Handler

```
public Class OpportunityTriggerHandler{
   public static void onAfterInsert(List<Opportunity> newOpp){

   }
   public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Opportunity> newOpp, List<Opportunity> oldOpp){

   }

}
```

This is the basic to create a handler,
newOpp and oldOpp is the value from trigger.new and trigger.old respectively.
now you can perform your operations in these method, let me know if you need more help.